# Realizar condição na trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma trigger que faz um update na minha tabela. queria saber como que faz para que a trigger somente seja executada se a coluna status for diferente do que já está na minha tabela, se caso for igual não acontece nada.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_anuencias
AFTER UPDATE ON anuencias
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO anuencias_auditoria
SET acao = 'update',
id_anuencia = NEW.id,
status = NEW.status,
modificadoem = NOW(); END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NEW` pega os novos valores e `OLD` pega os valores antigos, segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_anuencias
AFTER UPDATE ON anuencias
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
        INSERT INTO anuencias_auditoria
        SET acao = 'update', id_anuencia = NEW.id, status = NEW.status,
        modificadoem = NOW();
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Corrigiu meu erro aqui muito obrigado!