# Verificação de condição para lançar trigger

Tags: postgresql

Tenho está tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbtramite
(
  idtramite integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tbtramite_idtramite_seq'::regclass),
  dsdescricao character varying(255),
  dttramite timestamp without time zone,
  stnotificacao character varying(1),
  stretornada character varying(1),
  sttramitepublico character varying(1),
  idencaminhamento integer NOT NULL,
  idunidadeenvio integer NOT NULL,
  idusuarioemissor integer,
  idusuarioreceptor integer,
  CONSTRAINT tbtramite_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idtramite),
  CONSTRAINT fk_1pybfodhvhni89th78wu28av3 FOREIGN KEY (idunidadeenvio)
      REFERENCES public.tbunidade (idunidade) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_7njc4ihx8teld84auv7b83cht FOREIGN KEY (idusuarioemissor)
      REFERENCES public.tbusuario (idusuario) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_986qxqfo4nx3e6chji0q7mymg FOREIGN KEY (idusuarioreceptor)
      REFERENCES public.tbusuario (idusuario) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_iqha0kxcqwwfweibygg4p91xu FOREIGN KEY (idencaminhamento)
      REFERENCES public.tbencaminhamento (idencaminhamento) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.tbtramite
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

E tenho uma trigger que executa toda vez que um dado é inserido nesta tabela.

Porém eu gostaria de que a trigger fosse executada apenas quando na inserção do novo dado da coluna `idusuarioreceptor` fosse `NULL` e o campo da `idunidadeenvio` fosse `!=`(diferente) de `1`.

É possível executar esta verificação no momento de lançar a trigger? Ou então fazer uma procedure "leve" que verifique e está então chame a procedure mais pesada?

A trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER acerto_de_caminho_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON tbtramite
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE acerto_de_caminho();
```

Comment: coloque o codigo da funcao e da trigger

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de colocar os códigos pois a minha dúvida não é na função e no funcionamento dela, e sim se poderia fazer outra e nesta chamar ela. Ou então uma verificação de condição para o acionamento da própria trigger.

Comment: Mas em todo caso a trigger está ai, a função ainda estou desenvolvendo, mas não entra no escopo da pergunta

Comment: `IF (NEW.value <> 1 or new.value null)` Eu fiz uma assim certa vez: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_impressora()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
begin

IF (NEW.descricao <> OLD.descricao or new.codigoempresa <> old.codigoempresa)
THEN
UPDATE impressoras
SET codigoempresa = new.codigoempresa, setorinstalacao = new.descricao
where codigo = new.codigoimpressora; 

END IF;
return null;
end
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql` Espero que te ajude

Comment: Na function, isso não serve para ti?

Comment: @R.Santos servir, serve. Porém toda chamada de função é altamente custosa para o banco, e nesse caso em cada inserção ele ira chamar uma função e só la dentro que irá verificar

Comment: @R.Santos o que gostaria era de fazer essa verificação separada da função, apenas carregando a função caso as condições fossem estabelecidas

Comment: Isso não te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220238/realizar-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-na-trigger

Comment: @R.Santos e como ajuda, amanhã vou testar, mas creio que irá resolver meu problema

Comment: @R.Santos apesar dq este ai é em MySQL, torcer pro postgres se comportar igual

Comment: Tomara que de certo, não esquece do Feedback só